# Dropdown menu in a fixed navbar

Tags: drop-down-menu, css-position, navbar

I'm trying to add a dropdown menu inside a navigation bar.
I'm using the code provided by https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp, but when I try to fix the bar at the top of the page, the dropdown menu doesn't show anymore.

This is the code with a working dropdown menu:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
body {margin:0;}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div style="margin:20px;">
<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p style="height:3000px;">This should be a simple responsive webpage with a fixed navbar and a dropdown menu.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I add

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

...the dropdown menu disappears.
What should I do?
Thanks.